# Adding predict line from glm to ggplot2, larger than original data set

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm

I have included a sample data set just to demonstrate what I am trying to do.

```
Speed <- c(400,220,490,210,500,270,200,470,480,310,240,490,420,330,280,210,300,470,230,430,460,220,250,200,390)

Hit <- c(0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0)

obs <- c(1:25)

msl2.data <- as.data.frame(cbind(obs,Hit,Speed))

msl2.glm <- glm(Hit ~ Speed, data = msl2.data, family = binomial)
```

Doing What I want in the base package.

```
plot(Hit~ Speed, data = msl2.data, xlim = c(0,700), xlab = "Speed", ylab = "Hit", main = "Plot of hit vs Speed")

pi.hat<-(predict( msl2.glm, data.frame(Speed=c(0:700)), type="response" ))

lines( 0:700, pi.hat, col="blue" )
```

I am trying to recreate the above plot, but in `ggplot`. The error I have been unable to work around is the `aes(x,y)` have different lengths, which is true, but I want them to have different lengths.

Any ideas for this in gg?

Comment: You need to use two different `data=` statements: create a dataframe for the predictions, and pass this to `geom_line`, and use `data=msl2.data` in the `geom_point` : change the `x` and `y` in the `aes` as required. Or do it all i ggplot `ggplot(dat=msl2.data, aes(Speed, Hit)) + geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="glm", method.args=list(family="binomial"), fullrange=T, se=F) +
  xlim(0, 700)` Note you need `fulrange` and `xlim` to extend the plot

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much, this was driving me insane!

Answer (score 6):

You have a couple of approaches; the first does all the modelling 
inside of `ggplot`, the second does it outside and passes the relevant data
to be plot.

First

```
gplot(dat=msl2.data, aes(Speed, Hit)) + 
      geom_point() +
      geom_smooth(method="glm", method.args=list(family="binomial"), 
                  fullrange=TRUE, se=FALSE) +
      xlim(0, 700)
```

`fullrange` is specified so the prediction lines covers the x-range. `xlim` extends the x-axis.

Second

```
#Create prediction dataframe
pred <- data.frame(Speed=0:700, pi.hat)

ggplot() + 
  # prediction line
  geom_line(data=pred, aes(Speed, pi.hat)) +
  # points - note different dataframe is used
  geom_point(dat=msl2.data, aes(Speed, Hit))
```

I generally prefer to do the modelling outside (second approach), and use `ggplot` purely as a plotting mechanism.